# Find diagonals of lowest values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, comparison

I'm currently working on a text comparison tool. To make a proper comparison I want to align the texts with their common lines and once that is done at the lines with least change. I have a jagged Array with the Levenshtein distances from one line to another, now I need a way to find the "gretest common factor" parts from that array which is basically the longest diagonal of the lowest value. To make things even more interesting it is necessary that if the value is over 15, it needs to return -1 as this is seen as treshold for no common ground between the two lines. Because I can not shuffle the lines around, I can not assign the last line to the 2nd one if a different allocation has already been done in between. Plus the last index isn't necessarily allocated to the last line, in which case any "excess" lines that can't get a value assigned will also get a value of -1.

An example with the input on the left and the expected output on the right:

```
(04, 05, 07, 09, 16, 84, 13, 17, 01)  >>  04
(12, 13, 00, 05, 03, 00, 17, 19, 81)  >>  00
(81, 00, 15, 00, 00, 84, 16, 01, 44)  >>  00
(12, 06, 17, 83, 84, 12, 09, 15, 23)  >>  09
(01, 09, 14, 83, 81, 15, 06, 00, 00)  >>  00
(82, 83, 84, 81, 86, 80, 89, 87, 85)  >>  -1
(15, 12, 03, 00, 88, 82, 22, 56, 00)  >>  00
(00, 85, 15, 23, 45, 12, 04, 04, 16)  >>  -1
```

I assume I need a recursive algorithm of some kind, but I can't quite get a grasp on how to set it up. This might not seem too elegant but it's pre-existing code I have to deal with so I can't really change everything from the grounds up.

I know this sounds a bit weird, so thanks in advance for anyone having a hint for me on that one.

Comment: What did you try so far? This sounds like an exercise  that you only want to use, not do yourself ;)

Comment: See wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.  Not sure why you need recursion.

Comment: I tried it with a sub square matrix checking the diagonal for the currently desired search value (right now looping from 0 to 15) and if that returns wrong I rmove that square matrix check through the array depending on which dimension is bigger. The I plan on reducing the matrix size by 1 until I reach 1x1, then iterate the loop and repeat. If I get a result I cut those rows and columns and repeat the same for the reduced sub matrix from the current search value, until eventually the recursion bottoms out at every point.

Comment: I already implemented the Levenshtein distance itself (hence where I get the matrix above from) and the initial text comparison removing the identical lines (the 0s here are ignoring number values hence why that's a step further in the program), it's just that I'm a bit lost on how to set up this search through my Levenshtein distances to allocate the correct lines to another.